# Cython: How to convert C macro containing assignments

Tags: cython

Say I have the following C macros that I'm trying to convert to Cython. The issue is that the 2nd and 3rd modify the value of their arguments. How to convert this to an equivalent in Cython?

Example (some of the macros used in [siphash24](https://github.com/majek/csiphash/blob/master/csiphash.c)):

```
#define ROTATE(x, b) (uint64_t)( ((x) << (b)) | ( (x) >> (64 - (b))) )

#define HALF_ROUND(a,b,c,d,s,t)                 \
        a += b; c += d;                         \
        b = ROTATE(b, s) ^ a;                   \
        d = ROTATE(d, t) ^ c;                   \
        a = ROTATE(a, 32);

#define DOUBLE_ROUND(v0,v1,v2,v3)               \
        HALF_ROUND(v0,v1,v2,v3,13,16);          \
        HALF_ROUND(v2,v1,v0,v3,17,21);          \
        HALF_ROUND(v0,v1,v2,v3,13,16);          \
        HALF_ROUND(v2,v1,v0,v3,17,21);
```

**What I tried**:

I started going down a route of expanding the macro using f-strings, but it gets kind of messy:

```
def ROTATE(x, b):
    return f'<uint64_t>( (({x}) << ({b})) | ( ({x}) >> (64 - ({b}))) )'

def HALF_ROUND(a, b, c, d, s, t):
    return f"""
    {a} += {b}
    {c} += {d}
    {b} = {ROTATE(b, s)} ^ {a}
    {d} = {ROTATE(d, t)} ^ {c}
    {a} = {ROTATE(a, 32)}
"""

def DOUBLE_ROUND(v0, v1, v2, v3):
    return f"""
    {HALF_ROUND(v0,v1,v2,v3,13,16)}
    {HALF_ROUND(v2,v1,v0,v3,17,21)}
    {HALF_ROUND(v0,v1,v2,v3,13,16)}
    {HALF_ROUND(v2,v1,v0,v3,17,21)}
    """
```

So, for example, `DOUBLE_ROUND('v0','v1','v2','v3')` expands to:

```
    v0 += v1
    v2 += v3
    v1 = <uint64_t>( ((v1) << (13)) | ( (v1) >> (64 - (13))) ) ^ v0
    v3 = <uint64_t>( ((v3) << (16)) | ( (v3) >> (64 - (16))) ) ^ v2
    v0 = <uint64_t>( ((v0) << (32)) | ( (v0) >> (64 - (32))) )

    
    v2 += v1
    v0 += v3
    v1 = <uint64_t>( ((v1) << (17)) | ( (v1) >> (64 - (17))) ) ^ v2
    v3 = <uint64_t>( ((v3) << (21)) | ( (v3) >> (64 - (21))) ) ^ v0
    v2 = <uint64_t>( ((v2) << (32)) | ( (v2) >> (64 - (32))) )

    
    v0 += v1
    v2 += v3
    v1 = <uint64_t>( ((v1) << (13)) | ( (v1) >> (64 - (13))) ) ^ v0
    v3 = <uint64_t>( ((v3) << (16)) | ( (v3) >> (64 - (16))) ) ^ v2
    v0 = <uint64_t>( ((v0) << (32)) | ( (v0) >> (64 - (32))) )

    
    v2 += v1
    v0 += v3
    v1 = <uint64_t>( ((v1) << (17)) | ( (v1) >> (64 - (17))) ) ^ v2
    v3 = <uint64_t>( ((v3) << (21)) | ( (v3) >> (64 - (21))) ) ^ v0
    v2 = <uint64_t>( ((v2) << (32)) | ( (v2) >> (64 - (32))) )
```

Is there a better (more readable in the output) way of doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're happy to use `cdef` functions (i.e. only callable from Cython) then the idiomatic way would probably be to pass pointers rather than values:

```
cdef void half_round(int* a, int* b, int* c, int* d, int s, int t):
    a[0] += b[0]; c[0] += d[0]
    b[0] = ROTATE(b[0], s) ^ a[0]
    d[0] = ROTATE(d[0], t) ^ c[0]
    a[0] = ROTATE(a[0], 32)
```

You have to dereference the pointer, which can be done with either `[0]` as I've done here or `cython.operator.dereference`. You'd call it as

```
half_round(&a, &b, &c, &d, s, t)
```

If you want to make it more flexible so it works on types other than `int` you could use [fused types](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/fusedtypes.html)

If you want the functions to be callable from Python then you need to use `def` functions, which presents the problem that Python numerics are immutable. The best way would probably involve returning a tuple of the new values:

```
def half_round(a, b, c, d, s, t):
    a += b; c += d
    b = rotate(b, s)^a
    d = rotate(d, t)^c
    a = rotate(a, 32)
    return (a, b, c, d)
```

which you'd call as:

```
a, b, c, d = half_round(a, b, c, d, s, t)
```